# Bash snippet explanation wanted

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
i=0
while read M; do
    ((cd $DEST/cfg/puppet/modules/$M || exit 1
      [ -d .git ] && echo -n "$M: " && git pull) 2>&1 | prep $(printf %04d: $i) puppet/modules/$M) &
    i=$[i+1]
    [ $[ i % 20 ] = 0 ] && wait
done < $(dirname "$0")/modules-puppet.txt
```

Can someone please explain what the line `[ $[ i % 20 ] = 0 ] && wait` does in the above bash snippet?

Comment: Related: [What does a dollar sign followed by a square bracket $\[…\] mean in bash?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/209833/what-does-a-dollar-sign-followed-by-a-square-bracket-mean-in-bash)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code spawns a number of background tasks in a loop.   Each of these tasks run commands related to `git` and `puppet`.

The jobs may be spawned very fast and to not overwhelm the system, the code only runs 20 of them before waiting for all the currently running backgrund tasks to finish.  It is the call to `wait` that makes the script wait for all background tasks to finish before continuing, spawning another 20 jobs.

The arithmetic test that precedes the call to `wait` will be true for each value of `$i` evenly divisible by 20, i.e. for `$i = 20`, `$i = 40`, etc.

The syntax used for the arithmetic expansions, `$[ ... ]`, is obsolete `bash` syntax that nowadays would have been written `$(( ... ))` (which is portable).  The `%` operator is the ordinary modulus operator.

---

Apart from the use of the obsolete syntax, the shell also has a possible issue with quoting.  It's the variable expansions `$DEST` and `$M`, and also `$i`, that lack quoting, as does the two command substitutions.  If any of these contain or generate characters present in `$IFS` (space, tab, newline, by default), you may expect the script to fail or at least to misbehave.

The code also lacks a final `wait` after the loop, to properly wait for any of the last few jobs started by the loop.  This would not be needed if it can be guaranteed that the loop will *always* run `n*20` times (for some whole number `n`).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation

Answer (score 4):

`$[ i % 20 ]` is depreciated for arithmetic expansions, it was replaced by `$(())`.

`i % 20` is an arithmetic operation 'modulo'.

`[ $[ i % 20 ] = 0 ]` is a conditional statement and it's not standard, another syntax more readable and Posix could be:

```
 if [ "$(( i % 20 ))" -eq 0 ]
```

`&& wait` will be executed only if the return code of the previous command is equal to 0.

`[ $[ i % 20 ] = 0 ] && wait` will test modulo, if it's equal to 0 then `wait`.

I another way a complete syntax could be :

```
 if [ "$(( i % 20 ))" -eq 0 ] ; then
   wait
 fi
```

Comment: hmh? The only thing that looks nonstandard in `[ $[ i % 20 ] = 0 ]` is the deprecated arithmetic expansion which you already mentioned above.

Comment: Yes exactly i have updated the answer with more complete alternative (more readable).